# Intent to open a URL in another app, even if my app is set as default? (Android 11)

Tags: android, android-intent

My app has an intent filter to open URLs from some specific hosts, but I also need a feature to let the user view this URL in an external browser.

On Android 11, **if my app is set as the default app** for my intent filter, I'm no longer able to call `queryIntentActivities()` to get a list of other apps to populate a chooser. It only returns my app and nothing else.  And even just the plain `Intent.createChooser(...)` call produces only my app.

I've tried all kinds of variations of `<queries>` in my manifest, such as:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

I've even tried declaring the `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission, but `queryIntentActivities()` still returns only my app, even though I have Chrome and Firefox installed, and they should obviously be able to handle these URLs.
What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you use `assetlinks.json` to establish a link between your app and the hosts in question?

Comment: @CommonsWare  I did not. Does that have an effect on my ability to query other apps?

Comment: No, the other way around: I was worried that if you had used `assetlinks.json`, that might be why your app is tightly bound to those `Intents`. Have you tried your `queryIntentActivities()` test with some `Intent` that is unrelated to your app? That would help determine if the problem is with your `<queries>` element (e.g., in the wrong spot in the manifest) or if the problem is more specific to your app.

Comment: @CommonsWare When I try an intent with an unrelated URL, I am indeed able to get the correct items from `queryIntentActivities()`.  The placement of my `queries` tag is directly above the `application` tag.